# Forward subdomain to my own name server Names.co.uk

Tags: dns, active-directory, subdomain

I have a domain (for example test.example.com) that I wish to forward to my own network for Active directory purposes. The network already has a static IP address, and a DNS server set up that is successfully handling requests for the Domain controller internally. 
What I can't figure out is how to set it up so that I can connect to the Domain Controller from outside my Local network.
We use Names.co.uk for hosting, I've been messing around with the DNS settings for about a week, but the names will not resolve. can anybody explain what I need to dO?

FYI I've tried adding the SRV records to the names.co.uk DNS server, but they do not resolve back to the DC, I've also tried adding a NS record for the names.co.uk DNS server to get my DNS to resolve it, but that doesnt seem to work either!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS is resolves names using a hierarchy, with each level requiring NS record listing the low-levels. E.g. test.example.com: the 'com' zone has NS records for the 'example.com' nameservers and the 'example.com' zone has NS records for the 'test.example.com' nameservers.

So, not knowing your domain name, I can't check how it resolves. But I can say that to make it visible to the rest of the world, you need to have NS records created in the parent domain which point to your own nameservers (which should also contain NS records for your domain to pointing to themselves).